# Configure Reverse Proxy on NGINX with Grafana on Windows

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Context: I want to configure reverse proxy on NGINX for my grafana server running on local, is there any way I can do it. Didn't find any relative topic.

Note: Cannot use IIS for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change few configurations file for this, I guess you must be running Grafana and nginx on your local machine.

Note: Grafana server is running on 3000 and NGINX on 8099(this must be 80 on your machine)

1. **Changes in the Grafana config file**,

   Navigate to the Grafana config in the installation folder, for me I have used the `default.ini` file

   Update the value `domain = localhost` to `domain = my.perfdashboard.local.com`

   And the `root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/` to `root_url = http://localhost:3000` (this is not mandatory, but check if it didn't work)

   After these changes **restart** the **Grafana server**
2. **Changes in the NGINX configuration file**

   Navigate inside the conf folder inside the installation directory of NGINX.

   Inside the `https` section please add the following configuration,

   `map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade { default upgrade; '' close; }`

   `server { listen 8099; server_name my.perfdashboard.local.com root   html; index  index.html index.htm;`

   ```
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
   }
   location /api/alive {
       rewrite  ^/(.*)  /$1 break;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
   }
   ```

   }

   Restart the NGINX server
3. Change the host file on the windows machine,

   `localhost       my.perfdashboard.local.com   127.0.0.1       my.perfdashboard.local.com`

Now in the browser type my.perfdashboard.local.com:8099

Comment: Could you please also answer how to achieve this using IIS